# junit fails but passes when run through maven commandline

Tags: maven, junit

My `junit` fails when i run with `eclipse`. but when I run using `maven`, command line, it succeeds.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.security.core.authority.GrantedAuthorityImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Check the Spring dependencies. I think is possible that this error is generated by a library conflict..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, it was problem with jre. i changed from jre7 to jre6 (my project jre), it worked.

Answer (score 0):

These types of classcastexceptions often arise when you are either missing a dependency (jar file) or have a duplicate in your classpath/lib folder. Please check the folder where eclipse runs your tests for duplicate/missing jar files.